# In Arkham Horror, can my investigator only use Dragon's Eye on the drawn gate if she is the 'first player'?

Tags: arkham-horror

Dragon's Eye says

> **Any Phase:** Exhaust and lose 1 Sanity after drawing a gate or location card to draw a new card in its place

Does this mean the investigator owning it must be the 'first player' in order to affect the drawn gate card?

Comment: There are a few things that do affect the mythos deck, but I think they're all phrased clearly enough to avoid first player issues, like [Jacqueline Fine](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Jacqueline_Fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this item does not affect the gate tokens as they are placed by the **Mythos Cards**.

It is referring to **gate encounter** cards that you draw when you are in an other world location.

Also, the rules contains the contents of the game and the gate cards are listed separately to the gate tokens and mythos cards